# MySQL Clustering : Split data across multiple database server

Tags: mysql

We are implementing a chat application in android,IOS. we have to maintain all the messages on server. So i am planning to use 2 databases. One database will contain messages only. while second database will contain user information table and other tables.

We will be using MySQL Clustering  to have scalability using load balancing.

What i understood using mysql clustering is :-

it have data nodes which contains copies of database. so i want to know how data nodes will contains copies of 2 database.

How calls will be redirected to right data nodes

Please help me into it.

Comment: This question is more suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  how to move there?